# unpick a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, unpack

i have a list of 3 lists in Python

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]]
```

and i unpack using 3 lines of code

```
first= [m[0] for m in mylist]
second = [m[1] for m in mylist]
third = [m[2] for m in mylist]
```

I wish to find an efficient one line code for the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
first,second,third = zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]])

In [10]: first
Out[10]: (1, 10, 100)

In [11]: second
Out[11]: (2, 20, 200)

In [12]: third
Out[12]: (3, 30, 300)
```

Comment: For matrices (a list of lists where each row is the same length), `zip(*data)` is equivalent to the transpose function.

Comment: @IceArdor,  what advantage(s) does ndarray.transpose() have over zip?

Comment: I'm referring to the high-level concept of transposition. In Python it's called zip. In NumPy it's called transpose. In MATLAB it's called transpose or A'. I am unfamiliar with how numpy's `ndarray.transpose` function is written, so I'd be unable to speak to how it compares to Python's built-in `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you quite sure you shouldn't be using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for this?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> myarray = numpy.array(mylist)
>>> myarray
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 10,  20,  30],
       [100, 200, 300]])
```

just access them directly:

```
>>> myarray[...,0]
array([  1,  10, 100])
>>> myarray[...,1]
array([  2,  20, 200])
>>> myarray[...,2]
array([  3,  30, 300])
```

or give them names if you like:

```
>>> a, b, c = myarray
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b
array([10, 20, 30])
>>> c
array([100, 200, 300])
>>> d, e, f = myarray.transpose()
>>> d
array([  1,  10, 100])
>>> e
array([  2,  20, 200])
>>> f
array([  3,  30, 300])
```